# Highcharts: how to specify logarithmic scale for bar chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm new to Highcharts and I'm using a very simple Highcharts bar chart that shows two columns stacked horizontally.

The data values are 4.2 and 5691.7, but with such a large second value the chart shows only one column or the other but not both together.  If I use a small second value (e.g., 25) then it will show them stacked together.

I think I should use a logarithmic y axis; I've tried many ways to do that but so far no luck.

Here's the javascript:

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>

<script>
$(function () { 
    var myChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {type: 'bar'},
        title: {text: 'Chart Title'},
        xAxis: {categories: ['Category1<br>Category2']},
        yAxis: {title: {text: 'Value'}
        },

        series: [{name: 'Cat1',data: [4.2]},
        {name: 'Cat2',data: [5691.7]}]
    });
});
</script>
```

How do I specify logarithmic scale in the code shown above?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you not just add `type: 'logarithmic'` to your `yAxis` definition i.e. `yAxis: {title: {text: 'Value'}, type: 'logarithmic' }`

Comment: Yes, that works.  I tried that before with yAxis: , {type: 'logarithmic'}, {title: {text: 'Time in Seconds'}, but you showed me the right way.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Ah the subtle effect of an extra pair of `{}`!